# What is the meaning of "setting " here?

Tags: meaning

> Fine folk was **setting** on the white stone doorsteps of their
>   houses, and a girl threw me a handful of laylock sprays, and when I
>   said "Merci" without thinking, she said she loved the French. They all
>   was the fashion in the city.

This is from "Rewards and Fairies" "Brother Square-Toe" by Kipling.
http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi300.pdf
http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/rg_squaretoes1.htm

What does "setting" mean in this context?

> I would be glad if someone kindly explained it to me.

Comment: They, the fine folk, were *"placing"* themselves on the white stone doorsteps of their houses. **Set** - To put in a specified position or arrangement. **To be set** - Be situated or fixed in a specified place or position. (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/set)

Answer (score 1):

"Setting" means "sitting" in this context. It's a sort of colloquialism common in the southern US that Kipling uses here to show you something about the narrator (i.e. that he speaks with an accent).